# How to compile and check functionality of MiniJava programs?

Tags: java

I can write MiniJava code in Notepad++, however, I am confused as to how it can be checked, compiled and tested by myself.

Would greatly greatly greatly appreciate it, if someone could tell me how.

Comment: I'd start by downloading the JDK and Googling for a tutorial

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't do anything special with compilation; it's a text editor.  What is it exactly that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Barring all that, http://ideone.com/. Whatever MiniJava is.